# Beautifulsoup - Wrap first character in <span>

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

How can I wrap the first character in a tag using Beautifulsoup? I have a normal html document and I get the first p tag and the first character should be wrapped in a `<span>` tag (Space doesn't count as character, it shouldn't wrap space).

Example:

```
<p>
    Lorem Ipsum blablabla
</p>
```

This should be changed to this:

```
<p>
    <span class="first_word">L</span>orem Ipsum blablabla
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like the code below, i.e., creates a new `span` tag with the desired class then injects it into the HTML body. Some string manipulation is needed in order to put the `L` into this new tag and remove it from the existing text.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

markup = '<p>    Lorem Ipsum blablabla</p>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, "html.parser")

new_span = soup.new_tag("span", **{"class": "first_word"})
new_span.string = soup.p.string.strip()[0]

soup.p.string = soup.p.string.strip()[1:]
soup.p.string.insert_before(new_span)
print(soup)
```

Execute it and it will print

```
<p><span class="first_word">L</span>orem Ipsum blablabla</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

[`.new_tag()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring-and-new-tag) creates new tag and with `.string` property you can modify underlying text. For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''<p>
    Lorem Ipsum blablabla
</p>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

text, new_tag = soup.p.text.strip(), soup.new_tag("span", **{"class": "first_word"})
new_tag.string, soup.p.string = text[0], text[1:]

soup.p.string.insert_before(new_tag)

print(soup)
```

Prints:

```
<p><span class="first_word">L</span>orem Ipsum blablabla</p>
```

Comment: Ops, I have posted my answer and have not seen yours. I am upvoting yours.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but I accepted the other one, because it is easier to understand and that guy has fewer repuration than you. Thank you anyway, good work!